# Documents and Data Size on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite

Anyone know why my documents and data folder for my app is reaching 20MB even when my database which I only store simple strings is empty?

EDIT:
@olemoritz answered

Comment: Dunno. Why do I feel tired even though I've had eight hours sleep?

Comment: Probably was not a specific as I should have been but omz has answered the question now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How should we know? It's easy to find out though, just download the app's data to your Mac and have a look.

You can do that from the Xcode Organizer – select "Applications" under your connected device, click on the app you're interested in, and use the "Download" button. The result will be an xcappdata package that you can inspect by right-clicking it and selecting "Show Package Contents" in the Finder.

There are also third-party apps that let you inspect the documents and data of any application on a connected device, e.g. [PhoneView](http://ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/) or [DiskAid](http://www.digidna.net/diskaid).

Comment: After following your instructions I found that it is the Cache.db file but this is not something I added, maybe its part of the Apple MapKit framework.